# How to check whether we are fans fanpage or fanpages in FACEBOOK

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

How to check whether we are fans fanpage or fanpages

id pass on to the page method as follows:

page_id or page_id, page_id2, page_id3

```
function isFan(a) 
{
    FB.api('me/likes/'+a ,function(response) 
    {
    if (response.data.length == 0) 
    {
        $("#myModal2").modal()   
    }else{
        //OK i like
    }
    });

}
```

Comment: not one fanpage and many fanpages

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_loop

Comment: You need to ask for the users permissions before you can attempt this. Has the user authorised your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did it, how would anyone ever need.

```
function isFan(a) 
{
    var myString = a; 
    var fan_page_id = myString.split(',');

    for (var i=0;i<fan_page_id.length;i++)
    { 
        FB.api('me/likes/'+fan_page_id[i] ,function(response) 
        {
            if (response.data.length == 0) 
            {
                $("#myModal2").modal()   
                brake;
            }else{
                //OK i like
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't realistically think you can do the OR without some processing of your own. But you could use an fql query to retrieve a list of all the pages someone likes, then check if they match each one.

e.g // this would give you all a users fan page likes

```
  FB.api('/fql?q=' + urlencode("select page_id from page_fan where uid = me()")function(res){

 });
```

Then you would use your own code to validate that your lists are in the returned data. Alternatively you could do something like(make sure to urlencode the query)

```
  fql?q={"isFan":"select page_id from page_fan where uid = me()","myMatches":"select page_id from #isFan where page_id in (page_id1,page_id2)"}
```

the returned "myMatches" array in the JSON result would then contain only the likes against the ids you specify. So check the length of this result set, against the length of the number of page_ids you had initially.

```
   //pseudo code so prob some syntax errors here
   var page_ids = Array(1,2,3);
   var valid = true;
   var myQuery = ''; // <- your fql query here
   FB.api('/fql?q=' + myQuery, function(res)}
         var matches = res['myMatches'];
         if(matches.length == page_ids.length){
            valid = true;
         }elseif(matches.contains(single_id)){
            //some single id if you only want to check one
            valid = true;
         }else{
            valid = false;
         }
    });
```

The above could clearly be optimised, but it's just a starting point for you